# Txt file Access error with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing this school project in C# (Winforms), I created a temp file in a sub-form... using: `File.Create(filepath);` but when I try to delete it in the form closed event of my main form... then it gives error message. The file is in use by another process.
I tried:

```
    if (File.Exists(tmpFile))
    {
    File.SetAttributes(@tmpFile, FileAttributes.Temporary);
    File.Delete(tmpFile);
    }
```

But nothing good, I need better ideas and a logical reason why this error came? please

Comment: Have you got the file open in any other program?

Comment: no.. the sub form creates the tmp file, and the exit event in the main form should delete this file.... not using anywhere else. Btw does opening that path in windows explorer should bring this error?

Comment: I figured-out that instead of using `File.Create()`.... u should be using a `FileStream` to create custom tmp files..... Example:     
`string fileName = "C:\\" + Log.admin.ToString() + ".tmp";     
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);    
fs.Close();`   
Later the same file can be deleted using `File.Delete(fileName);`. Gud luck to all new ppl, thx @VinayC & everybody else for helping me outta this.

Answer (score 3):

`File.Create` returns the file stream. Make sure that you closes the stream (or any other handle to the file) before attempting to delete the file.

Comment: I figured-out that instead of using `File.Create()`.... u should be using a `FileStream` to create custom tmp files..... Example: `string fileName = "C:\\" + Log.admin.ToString() + ".tmp";    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);     fs.Close();` Later the same file can be deleted using `File.Delete(fileName);`. Gud luck to all new ppl, thx @VinayC & everybody else for helping me outta this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Path.GetTempFileName() to create the file.

You won't need to delete the file yourself. Windows will take care of it for you.

Comment: You can find out if you have the file open in any other program by using handle.exe which can be obtained from Microsoft via http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Comment: What if I need to create a temp file with a particular name only? For Ex: string filepath = "C:\\" + comboBox1.Text + ".tmp";

Comment: You should just be able to create the file and delete it just fine. Why bother altering the attribute of the file at all?